Help designing a multi load SSR circuit
beginner here.
I'm attempting to build an automation circuit with 3 resistive loads and 1 inductive load controlled via SSRs using RaspberryPi or Arduino
I'm following this post Wiring an SSR rasberry pi with an SSR-10DA on how to connect and control the SSR
And this is how I imagine to build it

My questions are:

Should I add any protection between the SSR and Raspberry Pi in case or SSR short circuit? (answers on other posts seem to be contradictory on this subject)
Should I add a snubber circuit between the inductive load and the SSR?
Do you see any problem in controlling 4 transistors and at least 2 temperature sensors  from Raspberry Pi? Note that I'm using an external DC source to power the transistors, LEDs and other sensors

Any other suggestions are welcome. Thank you for your time
Edit:
Here is the schematic. I used a simple tool to quickly simulate this circuit, but this doesn't mean that I will build it using a breadboard and batteries


Welcome! Please draw a schematic from your wiring diagram. You can use the built-in tool here by clicking on Edit then the schematic symbol.

"snubber circuit between the inductive load and the SSR" TRIAC snubber circuits are placed across (in parallel) with your SSR/TRIAC, not in series. Some SSRs/TRIACs, especially if you buy a complete module, are snubberless or have built-in snubbers. Check the datasheet for yours.

whatever you're doing, having 9V batteries labeled as "220V/AC" is a mistake. We also can't assess whether you correctly connected your relais, because that component picture doesn't tell us! Really, you need to draw a schematic. I will say that "220V loads which need to reliably switched" and "solderless breadboard with all of random friction holding contacts" don't go well together, at all.

Voting to close for lack of actual schematic (sadly)

Couple of schematic hints: Voltage sources are placed vertically. Positive voltages points up, negative points down, positive rails are drawn above negative and ground. Inputs on the left, outputs on the right with signal flow from left to right.
